# Getting rid of NA data points to create boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot, na, missing-data, graphing

I am trying to get rid of my phantom boxplot for this set of side-by-side boxplots. I know that it comes from missing data for gender, however, I can't figure out where in the code I am inserted `!is.na(ny$Gender)`. 
Here is my code,and the graph:

```
boxplot(ny$age ~ ny$Gender, col="orange", main="Distribution of age
                 and gender", ylab="Number of Users", xlab="Gender")
```

[image]

Comment: you could do `boxplot(age ~ Gender, ny, at = c(NA, 1:2))`

Comment: So, this worked!!!!!  I have to wrap my mind around this, but thank you!

Comment: @rawr maybe post as an answer?

Comment: Would love to, but there is no checkmark I can click on next to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have blanks in your dataframe under the `Gender` column, which is why you're getting an extra box.

See my reproducible example to see what the problem is and how to eliminate it. In this example `activ` represents `Gender` and `time` represents `age` for you.

```
attach(beaver2)

#View data
head(df)
> head(beaver2)
  day time  temp activ
1 307  930 36.58     0
2 307  940 36.73     0
3 307  950 36.93     0
4 307 1000 37.15     0
5 307 1010 37.23     0
6 307 1020 37.24     0

#rename the dataframe df
df <- beaver2

#introduce five blank spaces in the activ column to match your data 
 df[1:5,4] <- ""

#Visualize new dataframe
head(df)
  day time  temp activ
1 307  930 36.58      
2 307  940 36.73      
3 307  950 36.93      
4 307 1000 37.15      
5 307 1010 37.23      
6 307 1020 37.24     0

#Create boxplot with dataframe with blank spaces 

boxplot(df$time ~ df$activ, col="orange", main="Distribution of age 
and gender", ylab="Number of Users", xlab="Gender")
```

[image]

After you eliminate the blank spaces, you'll have a normal looking boxplot

```
df$activ[which(df$activ=="")] <- NA

#create new boxplot
boxplot(df$time ~ df$activ, col="orange", main="Distribution of age
             and gender", ylab="Number of Users", xlab="Gender")
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting this error message: when combining your suggestion with my code:> ny<-ny %>% filter(Gender=="Female" | Gender=="Male) 
+ + boxplot(ny$age ~ ny$Gender, col="orange", main="Distribution of age and gender", ylab="Number of Users", xlab="Gender")
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"ny<-ny %>% filter(Gender=="Female" | Gender=="Male) 
+ boxplot(ny$age ~ ny$Gender, col="orange"

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that ```df``` is the new name of the dataframe so in your code replace ```ny``` with ```df``` or you can rewrite my code as ```ny <- ny %>% filter...``` I gave the dataframe a new name incase you didn't want to permanently change the original

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I did that - but still an error message (see above)ny<-ny %>% filter(Gender=="Female" | Gender=="Male)+ boxplot(ny$age ~ ny$Gender, col="orange", main="Distribution of age and gender", ylab="Number of Users", xlab="Gender")
Error: unexpected symbol in "ny<-ny %>% filter(Gender=="Female" | Gender=="Male)+ boxplot(ny$age ~ ny$Gender, col="orange"

Comment: are you doing it as one line of code or two separate ones? It appears you have a ```+```. Try using filter in one line and then the boxplot in a second line of code. I'll modify my answer

Comment: two lines, connected by a + sign

Comment: You don't actually need ```+```. Even though it appears to be two lines on your screen, R actually reads it as one giant piece of code spanning two lines. I modified my answer so you should be able to copy and paste it and hopefully that works! The ```#``` wont be read as code, but rather just commentary. You can delete the ```#``` and it's corresponding text if you copy and paste my answer into R if wanted to

Comment: Your code makes sense to me, but I am still getting the same error message: ny <- ny %>% filter(Gender=="Female" | Gender=="Male) 
+ boxplot(ny$age ~ ny$Gender, col="orange", main="Distribution of age and gender", ylab="Number of Users", xlab="Gender")
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"ny <- ny %>% filter(Gender=="Female" | Gender=="Male) 
boxplot(ny$age ~ ny$Gender, col="orange"

Comment: It looks like you still have ```+``` written in your code. Could be the issue

Comment: the plus sign is automatically added by RStudio, not by me ...

Comment: I don't know why that is happening. I edited my answer so you can see why the extra boxplot is happening. I also showed you another way to eliminate the extra variable in `Gender`